# Problems relating to fibonacci sequence via induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction

Hey guys I have just started looking into induction and came across this problem regarding fibonnaci sequence that I don't quite know how to solve.

The ﬁbonacci sequence $\{f_n\}$ is deﬁned by
$f_0 = 0, f_1 = 1, f_n = f_{n−1} + f_{n−2}$ for all $n \ge 2$.
The ﬁrst few terms of the ﬁbonacci sequence are
$$0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597...$$

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$,
$$f_{2n} = \sum_{i = 1}^n f_{2i - 1}$$

For the Base Case I got that $f_{2n} = f_2 = 1$ and that $f_{2-1} = 1$.

Inductive Hypothesis: $f_{2(k)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} f_{2i - 1}$.

I am unsure how to solve for the inductive conclusion. If anyone could help me understand a solution that would be greatly helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your induction hypothesis isn't correct; you should assume that the result is true for the case $k$, and use it to establish the case $k + 1$. Use the definition of the Fibonacci numbers directly:

\begin{align*}
f_{2(k + 1)} &= f_{2k + 2} \\
&= f_{2k + 1} + f_{2k} \\
&= f_{2k + 1} + \sum_{i = 1}^k f_{2i - 1} \quad \text{(induction hypothesis)} \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} f_{2i - 1}
\end{align*}

Can you justify every step, and see how this proves the claim?

Comment: Step 1 is simple algebra
Step 2 is where I am a little confused on how to get there 
Step 3 is just subbing in the hypothesis as you said
Step 4 proves the statement. 

Can you help me understand step 2? Thanks so much!

Comment: @James If by step $2$ you mean that $f_{2k + 2} = f_{2k + 1} + f_{2k}$, then this is the definition of the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Oh, I understand that now but it shows that I am not familiar with Fibonacci sequence yet. I will try more examples to improve. Thank you very much!